# No such file or directory error on code blocks in Mac

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks, nosuchfileexception

```
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/leo1708/Desktop/C:C++ Code blocks/C programs/hello/bin/Debug/hello 
leo1708@Deeps-Air ~ % /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/leo1708/Desktop/C:C++ Code blocks/C programs/hello/bin/Debug/hello 
sh: /Users/leo1708/Desktop/C:C++: No such file or directory

Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.009 s
```

I am getting the above error while compiling C programs in Code blocks on my Mac m1.
I don't know what happened I have made so many programs, now suddenly the program is not compiling and giving me this error.please help.

Comment: Does the directory `Desktop/C:C++` exist?

Comment: Very wierd. Di you really have a folder called ` C:` in your Deskktop?